# Why does data remain after disk erase and factory reset - macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, disk-format, formatting, secure-erase

I've tried to erase and factory reset my MacBook, using *Erase All Content and Settings in System Preferences*. However, after completing the operation, and configuring the MacBook again, I can find the previous accounts in Mail, passwords of the wifi and all the previous settings of the last configuration. Why does this happen?

I don't have any backup on iCloud, I've checked many times. Anyway I choose to configure as a new MacBook.

How can I be sure the MacBook has been formatted if I find all this information after Erasing All Content?
I have a MacBook with T2 chip.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. While configuring your MacBook, did you sign in with an Apple ID? If you did, that's most probably where Mail account information (and passwords, if Keychain sync was active) came from.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, while configuring again my Macbook I Sign In with Apple ID. However, I've just checked Keychain and is empty, no password are saved in it

Comment: Could you confirm that Keychain is enabled in System Preferences > Apple ID? Keychain may look empty on your Mac, but, as you write in your answer, it looks like it stores your Wi-Fi password. If you own an iPhone/iPad, is Keychain enabled in General > [your Apple ID] > iCloud? If that's the case, your Wi-Fi password, which is stored in Keychain, is synchronized with iCloud, and that's most certainly where your Mac got it from.